# What javascript templating engine is usable with bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, template-engine, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that defines a bunch of divs I use for a script. Currently i am just using `$('<div/>').css({}).addClass()` etc.. but I would like to separate the divs from the code to promote readability. Are there any JS templating engines that support bookmarklets?

Answer (score 0):

Short: Probably not.

Long: It is usually not possible to say "no" and be sure, because rarely can anyone know everything about a subject. I can say that I keep an eye on the subject of bookmarklets and I've never seen such a thing. I could start to imagine how one might be created, but - depending on your goals - I doubt the effort wold be worthwhile.